Ceres solver, include issues
I created a new C++ project in Visual Studio that uses ceres, installed it using vcpkg. I did the static linking process that I do with other libraries (linking the include and .lib file) for ceres and glog. However when I include it, I get the following errors:

This is the include section:
    #include <iostream>
    #include "MFEM/mfem.hpp"
    #define GLOG_NO_ABBREVIATED_SEVERITIES
    #include "glog/logging.h"
    #include "ceres/ceres.h"

I have no idea how to resolve these errors, since these are coming from some of the header files. I have not programmed any functionality from ceres, just a blank main function yet. What am I missing?
